# JavaScript bind: Am I doing everything right?

Tags: asynchronous, axios, callback, bind

I'm confused about the syntax of the callback function.

```
class SomeClass {
   #privateVar;
   #axiosDefaultOptions;

   somePublicFunction(someID) {
      if (this.#privateVar === undefined) this.#getPrivateVar(someID, this.somePublicFunction);
      // some code
   }
   
   #getPrivateVar(someID, callback) {
      // some code
      // ---------
      axios.get('link', this.#axiosDefaultOptions).then((axiosResponse) => {
         // some code
         // ---------
         callback(someID);              // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading #privateVar)
         callback.bind(this, someID);   // No error, but somePublicFunction doesn't start again
         callback.bind(this)(someID);   // Works
         callback.bind(this, someID)(); // Works
      }
   }
}
```

If I do everything correctly, which option is better to use?
`callback.bind(this)(someID)` or `callback.bind(this, someID)()` ?